# Azure Scalable s Storage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machines, storage, azure

Am wondering if for some reason I chose to deploy an Azure VM that has 29GB storage for the sda1 (O.S Disk), can I resize this disk in anyway possible? (resizing the SAME DISK without attaching new disks).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: NO.

At the very end, you should really consider: - [Configure software RAID on Linux VMs in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-configure-raid/) . Definitely a good solution not only in case of need to extend the disk space, it also improves throughput.

Comment: Not sure why you're recommending setting up RAID on an OS disk. Trivial to attach 1TB data disks which can be easily mounted anywhere, up to 2 disks per core.

Comment: Yes you can do that, of course. Ghassan's question - as I understood it - was around extending the same space after you have provisioned the VM initially.

Comment: LeCampusAzure you got me right, I want to extend the same space, but we're talking Linux machines here, so you pretty sure it's impossible? And how do you suggest using RAID? What RAID model I mean?

Comment: The link above gives you an example of RAID 0 (strictly the "stripe" functionality you need)

Answer (score 0):

Azure OS gallery images for Linux are 29GB as you discovered (Windows OS gallery images are 127GB).

There are a few tools and blog posts floating around describing methods to increase the OS disk volume size. I'm not going to recommend a tool, but I'll point to the Microsoft TechNet article published [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2015/03/24/resizing-data-disks-in-the-cloud-on-microsoft-azure-with-windows-powershell/) which utilizes the PowerShell `Update-AzureDisk` cmdlet to resize the OS disk.

I dont' know if there's an equivalent Azure CLI command.

Aside from resizing, you may also attach 1TB data disks (and mount them anywhere in your volume), up to 2 disks per core (so, up to 64TB total attached storage). Attached disks are blob-backed, just like your OS disk, so the same level of durability. And you'll have the option to configure different disk cache options (none, read, or read/write).

Comment: Well thanks for the answer, but am looking for a tool on Azure CLI, it's for resizing a linux machine. Any ideas? Because I cant find any.